# Why is the data still null

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json

```
{"suggestions":["M.I.A.","M.","Mindless Self Indulgence","The Cure","Telefon Tel Aviv","M","J. Ralph","Jason Mraz","Carbon Based Lifeforms","Cycle of Pain","Chantal Kreviazuk","-M-","ayumi hamasaki","R.E.M.","Donny McCaslin","Penfold","HEALTH","R. Kelly","DJ Khaled","Eminem","Spose","T.I.","The Lonely Island","H.I.M. (His Infernal Majesty)","Dropkick Murphys","Taylor Swift"],"query":"m"}
```

which i am getting from this ajax call

```
$.getJSON('<%= ajax_path("artistName") %>', req, function(data) {
   //create array for response objects
   var suggestions = [];
   console.log(data);
   //process response
   $.each(data, function(i, val){                                
      suggestions.push(val.name);
   });
   console.log(suggestions);
   //pass array to callback
   add(suggestions);
});
},
```

why is my suggestions still null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to loop through, `suggestions` is already an array available for use, so replace this:

```
var suggestions = [];
console.log(data);
//process response
$.each(data, function(i, val){                                
    suggestions.push(val.name);
});
console.log(suggestions);
```

With this:

```
var suggestions = data.suggestions;
console.log(suggestions);
```

Then your array being passed to `add()` will have the results from your JSON response.